# Particular solution to a second-order differential equation with trigonometry

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The Problem**
$$y'' + 4y = \tan\left(2t\right)\sec\left(2t\right)$$

**What I know**
I know that the general solution for the equation is:

$$ y_H = K_1e^{2t} + K_2e^{-2t} $$

**The Question** 
what is the format for the guess of the particular solution for this equation?

**My Guess Using Variation of Parameters**

$$y_p = -e^{2t}\int{\frac{tan(2t)sec(2t)e^{-2t}}{-4}} + e^{-2t}\int{\frac{tan(2t)sec(2t)e^{2t}}{-4}}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: Variation of Parameters.

Comment: See my answer here for an example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474830/how-do-you-solve-this-differential-equation-using-variation-of-parameters

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your general solution.
If you have a solution to the homogeneous equation, here $e^{2t}$, try $f(t)e^{2t}$.  That will reduce your equation to a first-order equation in $g(t)=f\,'(t)$

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a mistake from the beginning since r^2+4=0 gives r=2i and r=-2i. Then your general equation is
C[1] Cos[2 t] + C[2] Sin[2 t]
and not
C[1] Exp[2 t] + C[2] Exp[-2 t]
I hope I am right since, apparently, nobody noticed that.